# finding text in a string and replacing whole string with another string + R

Tags: r

I have this vector/array in R programming that I would like to find "WIND" (upercase or lower case) and replace the whole text with "WIND"

```
> b
 [1] "TORNADO"                   "TSTM WIND"                 "HAIL"                     
 [4] "FREEZING RAIN"             "SNOW"                      "ICE STORM/FLASH FLOOD"    
 [7] "SNOW/ICE"                  "WINDTER STORM"             "HURRICANE OPAL/HIGH WINDS"
[10] "THUNDERSTORM WINDS"
```

Fo r  example "TSTM WIND"  would be come "WIND". So would "WINDTER STORM" and "HURRICANE OPAL/HIGH WINDS"...etc

I have tried this but no joy

```
> gsub("*WIND*","WIND",b,ignore.case=T)
 [1] "TORNADO"                   "TSTM WIND"                 "HAIL"                     
 [4] "FREEZING RAIN"             "SNOW"                      "ICE STORM/FLASH FLOOD"    
 [7] "SNOW/ICE"                  "WINDTER STORM"             "HURRICANE OPAL/HIGH WINDS"
[10] "THUNDERSTORM WINDS"       
>
```

this show the ones that meet my criteria

```
> grepl("*WIND*",b,ignore.case=T)
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're replacing all matches with the same string, you can use `[<-`

```
b[grepl("WIND", b)] <- "WIND"
```

You can also use `sub`

```
sub(".*(WIND).*", "\\1", b)
```

Both resulting in

```
 [1] "TORNADO"               "WIND"                  "HAIL"                 
 [4] "FREEZING RAIN"         "SNOW"                  "ICE STORM/FLASH FLOOD"
 [7] "SNOW/ICE"              "WIND"                  "WIND"                 
[10] "WIND"
```

Comment: thaks and perfect, what are the `dots` in `".*WIND.*"`

Comment: `.*` in regex basically says, "match everything".  So this matches everything up to and including `WIND` and then everything after it.  I believe the `.` by itself means "any character"

Comment: Here's a good reference http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing

Comment: How would I insert a variable in place of "WIND", say looping through an array /Is it something like `list<-gsub(".*"+i+".*",i,list,ignore.case=T)`

Comment: to answer my own Q i usesd `pattern<-paste(".*",i,".*",sep="")  list<-gsub(pattern,i,list,ignore.case=T)`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is in the `stringr` package.

```
require(stringr)
str_replace_all(b, ignore.case(".*WIND.*"), "WIND")
```

This should do what you're looking for. Cases like these are why stringr was made.